# Format text in a <textarea>?

Tags: css, html, textarea

Textareas are great because of some built in functionality (scrollbars). How can I format `<spans>` of text inside of the `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you need to customize your textarea, reproduce its behavior using another element (like a DIV) with the `contenteditable` attribute.

It's more customizable, and a more modern approach, textarea is just for plain text content, not for rich content.

```
<div id="fake_textarea" contenteditable></div>
```

The scrollbars can be reproduced with the CSS overflow property.

You can use this fake textarea in a form normally, i.e: if you have to submit its content through POST method, you could do something like(with jQuery):

```
<input type="hidden" id="fake_textarea_content" name="foobar">
```

...

```
$('#your_form').submit(function()
{
  $('#fake_textarea_content').val($('#fake_textarea').html());
});
```

Comment: contenteditable isn't all poines and rainbows. This article is a great readup that I wish I hade seen before trying to use contenteditable on a few of my projects: https://medium.com/content-uneditable/contenteditable-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-261a38555e9c#.v0d5rghdl. It seems so good, but it's terribly flawed.

Comment: "the project is either dead or full of most brutal hacks which seem to work ... The developer joins the “contentEditable is evil” club" :)

Answer (score 12):

You Can't style the content of a text area separately, you have to use `<div>`s, or something similar.

Do you Want Something like this:?

http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/

```
$('.editable').each(function(){
    this.contentEditable = true;
});
```

This allows you to edit the content of a div, and it will still look like a textarea,

**Bold will now Work.**

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/XNkDx/2199/](http://jsfiddle.net/XNkDx/2199/) I just added few lines to show you how this work for real. And, +1 for you my friend, nice little script

Comment: ...I said that a question was a duplicate of itself. How did nobody notice?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use HTML inside `TEXTAREA`.

Scrolling can be applied to any element by adding `overflow: auto` and fixed `width` and/or `height`.

Answer (score 2):

You can user html editors for web like CKEditor to be able to format the data in text area. Check this http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to submit the "fake" text area is including the following lines inside the form tag

```
<form onsubmit=" $('#fake_textarea_content').val($('#fake_textarea').html());">
</form>
```

Comment: I think you left something out of your answer.

Comment: uppsss.. fixed it. Cheers!