# Is it possible to display bold and non-bold text in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want this:

```
<textarea>The <b>color</b> is black.</textarea>
```

Instead of the `<b>` and `</b>` i want the text "color" to be shown in bold.

Is this possible?

Comment: As far I know textareas don't accept any HTMLy only pure text if you're not using any jQuery / JS tools or plugins.

Comment: you need a rich text editor - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903525/rich-text-html-editor-for-websites-i-can-use-for-free

Comment: I think this is what you wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea answered by @Marcus Ekwall take a look at his [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/)

Comment: codemirror will let you do this while still acting like a textarea instead of a div... that's to say that the .value will not have the presentational markup, not sure if you want it just shown or actually integrated into the string.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, I couldn't think of any other solution. But as others pointed out, I think you might want to use a WYSIWYG html editor plugin. such as [this](http://imperavi.com/redactor/).

Comment: @tastro No worries, as long as you got what you need :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For these cases, avoid use something pure text area, use wysiwyg html editor.

Here are some ideas for you:

[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

[niceditor](http://nicedit.com/)

Comment: @tastro, I really don't recommend because tomorrow you need configure italic/border/etc, then, it's better prevent using these editors.

Answer (score 19):

You Can't style the content of a text area separately, you have to use <div>s, or something similar. This may be a duplicate of:

[Format text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea)

Do you Want Something like this:?

http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/

```
$('.editable').each(function(){
    this.contentEditable = true;
});
```

this allows you to edit the content of a div, and it will still look like a textarea,

**Bold Works.**