# How to display part of text bold/underlined that is from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an event page, when I create a new record I also add Event Details and save it to my database. However there are some parts in the text that I would like them to be underlined or Bold

when Displaying the data I use `<textarea>`

```
  <textarea readonly="readonly" class="NoBorder ">@(Model.TE_DESCRIPTION)</textarea>
```

so is there a hack to achieve this? I hoped  placing `<b>` or `<u>` tags to the text to work but it does not.

any help or suggestion is much appreaciated

**Edit**
it is not important if I use a  or

or  to dipslay data..
My issue is I fetch the text from database, let's say that following is the string I saved to the database

< b > This part of the text is bold the rest are not

the above text is displayed as it is written above however I want it to be displayed like

**This part of the text is bold** the rest are not

I'm sorry for the bad english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display bold and non-bold text in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456295/is-it-possible-to-display-bold-and-non-bold-text-in-a-textarea)

Comment: This is not the issue, I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: You cant do it with textarea. Use div like as  <div>@Html.Raw(Model.TE_DESCRIPTION)</div>

Comment: @EsatARSLAN Thank you, this is what I've been trying to do!