# Set word background color in textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I wish to highlight words and phrases in a textarea with different colors, like this:

[image]

How would you recommend I do this? If its not possible with a textarea, what would you recommend instead?

My application will use this text area to enable the client to enter a short story. Words and phrases will be colored based on their frequency, by the application. I will store all the words from the text area in an array, for example the text:

`"Once upon a time, I met a woman called Nora. She was "`

will be represented internally as:

`"once", "upon", "a", "time", "i", "met", "a", "woman", "called", "nora", "she", "was"`.
This array will then be used when applying the appropriate colors.

I will inquire about an efficient way of updating the array as the text changes via a separate question, but please keep this in mind when answering this question.

Comment: `<textarea>` can't do that; You may want to use `<div>` with [`contenteditable`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format text in a <textarea>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea)

Comment: I would love to see the answer to THIS question.  It strikes me as very different to the 'Format text in a <textarea> mentioned above.  This question from the example given, wants to format text inside (innerHtml) the text area.  I don't think you can do it with out some gymnastics.

Answer (score 2):

A textarea might be the wrong way to do it.

I suggest using an ordinary division or similar element, then wrap what you want to highlight in a `<span>` with a class for each colour. You can enable `contenteditable` to allow the user to edit the text inside the element.

Example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is some text. I am <span class="blue">highlighting it</span>. It's <span class="yellow">pretty obvious</span> isn't it?
</div>
```

If you want the textarea appearance, in your CSS just apply your style to both textareas and this element.

Answer (score 0):

Display all of your text from array into a div element.

For each element you wish to be selected, wrap the text inside of a span element.

Set the background color for the span element based on what color you want.