# How to highlight a part of text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

Is there a way to highlight a part of text in text-area?

Say, the text is `Hi @twitter @twitpic` and now I would like to highlight **@twitter** and **@twitpic** only and not **Hi**. Is that possible?

This has to happen on the fly.

PS: I don't want to use **iFrame**

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea

Comment: are the texts you want to highlight always starting with @  ?

Comment: @pay4m -->words either start with @ or #. Similar to twitter editor. Thanks

Comment: @spezzino --> I cannot use span or div to compensate textarea as I am feeding this text area to another jquery plugin http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/

Comment: you can't highlight a word without wrapping a tag around it, or at least I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

without wrapping a tag around the specific words, you cannot highlight it (or as i said, at least I have no idea how to).
but if there is no problem with wrapping tags, you should use regEx.

for words starting with @ :

```
replace(/@([^ ]+)/g, '<span class="atsign">@$1</span>');
```

and for the words starting with # :

```
status.replace(/#([^ ]+)/g, '<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
```

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c26r9/1/)

**EDIT:** you can replace

```
var status = 'I tweeted something #one #two @three @four';
```

with

```
var status = $('#phrase').text();
```

Comment: --> how to highlight the combination of both at a time? My code seems to be wrong. Please have a look at it 'var editorData = $('#taEditor').val();
        editorData = editorData.replace(/@([^ ]+)/g, '<span style="color:#3366CC">@$1</span>');
        editorData = editorData.replace(/#([^ ]+)/g, '<span style="color:#3366CC">#$1</span>');
        $('#livePreview').html(editorData);'

Comment: To do both at the same time try `/[@#]([^ ]+)/g`

Comment: @gaynorvader -> Your suggestion works but I loose # or @ from the word.

Comment: This doesn't work in a textarea, which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: to do it in a textarea there is a good explanation here: https://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/

Answer (score 11):

Use `setSelectionRange` method on that text

Sample code:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
        <button id="hgh">Hightlight @twiiter</button>
    </section>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {

            var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
            var checkError = document.getElementById("hgh");

            checkError.addEventListener("click", function () {

                var index = textarea.innerText.indexOf("@twitter");
                if( index >= 0)
                    textarea.setSelectionRange(index, index + 8);
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for an answer where I could highlight certain words in the textarea. Did'nt find an answer in this thread. So, adding how I did it:

For this example, you would do something like:

1. Download and include scripts from here: http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/index.html
2. And use this:

   ```
   <script>
   $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
    words: ['@twitter', '@twitpic'],
    id: 'demoCustom',
    caseSensitive: false
    // or a regular expression like -> words: ['@([^ ]+)']
   });
   </script>

   <style>
    #demoCustom mark {
     padding:0 3px;
     margin:-1px -4px;
     border-radius:0.5em;
     border:1px solid pink;
    }
   </style>
   ```

More Examples: http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty simple using jQuery.

HTML part:

```
<textarea id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Praesent vitae arcu tempor neque lacinia pretium.</textarea>
<button id="search">search</button>
```

JS part:

```
$(function(){
  $("#search").click(function(){
    var area   = $('#test');
    var findWord = "rhoncus";
    var index = area.val().indexOf(findWord);
    area.focus().prop({'selectionStart': index, 'selectionEnd': index+findWord.length})          
  })
})
```

Just change the variable findWord for whatever you want to highlight.