# how to color specific word in textarea in c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, css

I have a TextArea control in my ASP.NET page which gets populated with a paragraph containing multiple sentences from the database. After this data gets populated in the TextArea control, I need to search for a few words in them and highlight them in different color

Comment: you can try ckeditor plugin for your text area.it will be helpful to you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Rich text box instead of textarea.
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Use RegEx**
Here is a link:

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518310/how-to-highlight-a-part-of-text-in-textarea)

[Here too](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~jmunoz/)