# Display a string in textarea with html/css styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor

I have a string that contains some font css styling built into the string. I am using Razor and I want to display the result within a textareafor or something similar. Is there a good way to do this?

Here is what the string looks like:

```
<font color="DD0000"><b>7/10/2014 - CFENDALL</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Hi Mike - I have invoice 133528E for PO 158960 - This is past due - Please let me know when PO is received.  Thank you.  Cynthia</font>
```

I want the styled version to appear in the textarea but as of right now it just displays the string without applying the css.

Here is what I currently have in my view:

```
    <div class="editor-field" id="summary">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { @readonly = "readonly"})
    </div>
```

Comment: [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `textarea` is not meant to act as a container; it is an input for text. If you want to style the contents *as a whole*, then you can apply style **to the text area itself**; however, individual pieces of text in the textarea cannot be styled. One way you could do this is by loading the content of the textarea into a div -- which CAN be styled.

Check out Coyier's examples on how to style textareas: http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/ .

Likewise, here is a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea). The gist from the question is to dump your textarea content into some "fake" textarea which is actually a div. Cue example from question using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="fakeTextarea"></div>
<textarea id="realTextarea"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#fakeTextarea').html( $('#realTextarea').val() );
```

Feel free to check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWP2k/).

Answer (score 1):

Not for a textarea as you can't style individual lines within it. You must do something like this:

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="messages"><code contenteditable="true"></code></div>
```

---

**JScript**

```
var messageBox = $('.messages code');

function sendMessage(message, color){
    var color = (typeof color === "undefined") ? "inherit" : color;
    var fullMessage = "<span style=\"color:" + color + "\">" + message + "</span>";
    messageBox.append(fullMessage);
    /*messageBox.scrollTop(messageBox[0].scrollHeight); keeps the area scrolled down */
}

/*You can call this like:*/
var message = "<b>7/10/2014 - CFENDALL</b> Hi Mike - I have invoice 133528E for PO 158960 - This is past due - Please let me know when PO is received.  Thank you.  Cynthia";

sendMessage(message, "#DD0000");
```

### *Updated fiddle to add some CSS

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/G7BB9/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea{
    color: #dd0000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

not sure if this is the answer you asked for, but it would be how you style a text-area.
There are other really dirty ways with positioning that you could use, but not recommended

Comment: Note from the question that the user "[wants] the styled version [of the string] to appear in the textarea." Applying CSS to the textarea will style *the textarea* -- not the string.