# How to highlight searched keyword

Tags: javascript, html

I am searching the data from database and get result and place the result in a `textarea`.

How can I highlight the searched keyword?

Answer (score 1):

You can't since `textarea` doesn't support advanced formatting, like coloring a part of the text.

You can find a workaround in this post ([Format text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12831101/993547)), which uses a `div`. You can generate some HTML from your search which has some `span`s which are assigned with a CSS class, which you can format as you wish.