# is it possible to have multiple colors inside an html <textarea> element

Tags: css, colors, textarea, contenteditable

I am creating a friendly cms and I want to use multiple colors in `<textarea>` element. I would need this very badly and can not come up with a solution.

I need 3 colors one for tags a.k.a. red `<title>`, second orange for atributes aka class="myclass" and third for other - text between the tags.
Best solution would be to use black for all text and background-color for tags and atributes. Any hints?

The difference from contenteditable atribute is that I want to display IN HTML ONLY tags with classes I define, eg for red:

```
<style>
span.red{color:red; } /*because in SO this doesn't see nice, using inline css here, leaving this intact*/

</style>
```

I want to display this:

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>
<h1>title</h1>
<strong>hi hi</strong>
</div>
```

... as this below:

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>
<span class="red" style="color: red;">&lt;h1&gt;</span>title<span class="red" style="color: red;">&lt;/h1&gt;</span>
<span class="red" style="color:red;">&lt;strong&gt;</span>hi hi<span class="red" style="color: red;">&lt;/strong&gt;</span>
</div>
```

I do not know if this is a PHP parser issue or if can it be solved simpler or even in html (define an exception ;-) ... fantasizing).
I have a hunch that I could do it with the help of htmlentities(), but do have a faintest idea how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format text in a <textarea>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea)

Comment: Do you have any code that you have already tried on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradient to set more than one color to your textarea

```
textarea {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I have been looking for - I am not coloring for beauty, but for functionality to tell dummy user not to touch html tags inside file that is displayed (yes, it is for a CMS) but to allow him to do that if he wants that and also coloring atribute values inside tags with another color, because even dummy user sometimes needs to do=change that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use library to highlight user input as html.

**For example:**

http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about

http://codemirror.net/demo/tern.html

They work based on contenteditable element. In textarea you can not have multiple colors.