# HTML + JS: Best way to style up textarea's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

What is the best way to style up content in the HTML `textarea` element. My goal is to have parts of text in my `textarea` red (for example), so I would do `<span style="color: red">My text part</span>` but this way the `textarea` shows everything including my HTML code `<span> ... </span>` as its value.

Next thing I tried is to overlay `div` with my `textarea` in which would be my desired code width `<span> ... </span>` code shown correctly with red styled text and without HTML code. User will edit `textarea`'s value which would be processed and shown in my `div`. But this method seems to me too dirty. What is your advises?

Comment: Have you looked into using web text editor like ckEditor, TinyMCE etc

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling text inside a textarea is not possible, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12831155/2127296). You could use a plugin like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/), which will show a text editor in the place of your textarea, and there you can put the style that you want to the text.