# Google-translate alike front-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As many people have used google translation, I want to create a website like "translate.google.com" based on my own machine translation system. I hope somebody can help me with the following questions since I'm not experienced in web development, .

1. The input area of google-translate is a textarea . When a user hovers on the **target** phrase, the corresponding **source** phrase was highlighted. How can I achieve such effects? Do I need to modify the textarea or use span-like control?
2. The output area of google-translate seems to be not a textarea. When a user clicks on the **target** phrase, it triggered an event and make communication with the back-end, then the corresponding translation options are displayed right on the target phrase. I want to make the position of the translation options the same as google-translate, how can I achieve this without refreshing the whole page?

Any comment will be welcome.

Comment: 1. Instead of a textarea you can use divs and spans with the `contenteditable` attribute - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea 2. You'll need to use ajax to get the translation data without reloading the page, there are countless examples on the internet and jQuery has pretty easy to use functions like `$.post` and `$.get` for making ajax calls. Now I just want to add that you'll have to identify the corresponding translated and not translated versions of the words possibly  with `classes` and `ids`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wonder if you have any idea about how to display the translation options when user clicking on the target phrase. As I know, clicking on a span or div cannot trigger a service request, do I need to use "button" to represent each phrase? Thank you again.

Comment: By the way, I'm using C# and must public an exe file to be WCF service

Comment: 'As I know, clicking on a span or div cannot trigger a service request' that is not true. With jQuery you can easily catch the click on a `div` or a `span` like `$("#myDivId").click(function(){..//code here will be executed});` You'll just need to come up with some logic like if you click the `span` of class `span2` it will highlight the span of class `span2Translated`. When you spit out your translation that is when you'll add the classes to your elements. I have nothing to offer you in the C# area

Comment: The dropdown box used by google translate looks like not a traditional dropdown box, do you know any method to achieve it? Thank you a lot

Comment: the dropdown box for the picking a language?

Comment: No. When you click on the target side phrase, there will be a list shown below the phrase, which lists some translation options.