# downloaded file doesn't contain proper breaks - keeps br

Tags: javascript, html

i have a download script that takes user input, generates a specific file with specific line breaks, and then outputs that file and prompts the user to download it.

```
    function download(filename, text) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);

        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();

        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }

    download('test.txt', toExport);
```

however `toExport` contains a lot of `<br/>`.
how can i get this to come across in the text file? currently they're just showing up as `<br >` and not actually breaks.

Comment: Need to see how you are creating the content of toExport. If it's an element, try `.innerText` not `.innerHTML`.

Comment: it's continuously appended to a `<textarea>` and then i'm grabbing it by using `$('#text-area').html(); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta replace all `<br>` with newlines `\n`. `<br />` tags only works in browser, common editors will read it as regular text.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, [you can't with a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea). But you can make an element editable and do it that way.

```js
let editable = document.querySelector('.editable');

function html() {
  console.log(editable.innerHTML);
}

function text() {
  console.log(editable.innerText);
}
```

```css
.editable {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" contentEditable="true">Lorem 
Ipsum

Dollar
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="html()">HTML</button>
  <button onclick="text()">Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what OP has asked for, you probably misunderstood the question.

Comment: @stuntHanks I was working off of his comment to his question. And my answer shows an example about how to achieve his goal.  But thanks?

Comment: I haven't seen the comment, sorry.