# How is formatting in <textarea> being done?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to build a comment system and it just came to realization. Text area cannot be formatted meaning no paragraphs, line breaks etc can be retained. I know stackoverflow uses a text editor instead of text area but on sites such as Reddit, it is just a plain textarea.

Is formatting the value of textarea being done with javascript?

Comment: You should use a plugin for that. It depends if you use jQuery, Angular or other client-side frameworks on what plugins you can use.

Comment: Maybe fake textarea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea

Comment: @ice13 I'm using Vue to build a simple blog website with commenting system. I'd like to save the comments to database with formatting preserved. Any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: @Flowen I've read that thread, not quite what I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In textarea values, the line breaks are marked with the EOL character (/r, /n or /r/n). Those characters do not have any visual impact on HTML (only in the source). What you want is to make them visible by replacing them with `<br/>` or `<p></p>`

Your best bet is to replace those characters when displaying the text, so your user won't see the tags if they edit their comments.

This, with some more options like adding `<b></b>` and `<i></i>` when text is surrounded by single or double asterisks ( * ) would give you a fairly close formatting to stackoverflow, which does use a textarea unlike you believe.

EDIT: Like suggested by others, there exists WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editors which means the user sees exactly the result of his comment, and can edit the styles just as if they were in Microsoft Word or similar. This approach might be fine, but it is way overkill for comments. Reddit and stackoverflow allows to see a PREVIEW of your content before posting, but they do not allow to see, while typing, the live results. 2 solutions, both work, you just need to choose the one you think would be best for your users.

Also, when using a simple textarea, you might want to look at markdown, you could provide markdown support (which is very close to how we format our text here) that way some people won't even need to (re)learn how to format their text on your site, as it is the same as other sites / tools.

EDIT2:

Here is a fast/basic implementation of 4 styling applications: single line-break, double line-break to paragraph, double asterisk to make bold, single asterisk to make italic.

```js
$("#editor").on('keyup', function(e) {
  var input = $(e.target).val();
  input = input.replace(/[\n]{2}/, '</p><p>');
  input = input.replace(/[\n]{1}/, '<br/>');
  input = input.replace(/\*\*(.+)\*\*/, '<strong>$1</strong>');
  input = input.replace(/\*(.+)\*/, '<em>$1</em>');
  $('#result').html('<p>' + input + '</p>');
});
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
#editor{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor">

</textarea>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a few things clear. A textarea is simply that; a "text area". It holds plain text, and for the record, a textarea DOES retain line breaks. But you are correct; it has no functionality beyond that. No styling, it doesn't automatically insert paragraph tags, or have any further advanced functionality you sound like you are looking for.

It sounds to me like what you are looking for a web-based WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor. Something to give simple functions like bold text, maybe indentation/text aligning buttons, and so forth. The two most popular/well-known ones are CK Editor and Tiny MCE, both of which utilize Javascript to run:
https://ckeditor.com/
https://www.tinymce.com/

TinyMCE is the simplest. They have CDN's with their libraries so all you have to do is copy and paste a few lines of code to get it to work. Both libraries come with plugins, both free and premium, which offer advanced functionality like image uploading and etc.

Your second approach; as of HTML 5, HTML elements can now use the **contenteditable** attribute which allows the HTML content in a webpage to become editable. You can create a div/element and manipulate those elements to have styling. This approach has a few pitfalls, the biggest being compatiblity for  older browsers and second, posting that data to other web pages, which forces the use of Javascript to copy the content of the HTML element to a hidden input or textarea.

This person (whom I believe came from this site) developed a useful WYSIWYG editor for going the contenteditable approach:
http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/

Comment: "compatiblity for older browsers" should be ok... Even IE6 supports it. It was specified in HTML5 but most HTML4 capable browser had implemented it before.

Comment: Helped me a lot, because i didn't know that the stuff which I was looking for was called "WYSIWYG editor". Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want advanced formatting, such as `<em>` and `<strong>`, you'll want to use an element (most likely a `<div>`) with the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute enabled. Example:

```html
<div contenteditable><em>Hello</em> <strong>world</strong></div>
```

To make a user interface to allow the user to format the text, see:

- [Get caret position in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972014/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div)
- [HTML Formatting (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp)

Comment: =/ there's no formatting capability on your code. how do you make something bold or italic by yourself?

Comment: @Salketer you'd need some front-end functionality to make that work. I'll edit my answer to add more info.