# Changing textarea textcolor based off of what word is typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, syntax-highlighting

I am currently working on a website where I would like to add a textarea element to the html to allow the user to type in things. However, I would also like the text color of certain words to change while the user is typing. I.e. if they type "print" it turns red and all the rest of the text is still white. I originally thought that I could use jquery to change the html and add spans around the "print" text but that does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: share your code

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot apply styles inside a textarea. You would want to use a "fake" textarea which is basically a contenteditable div. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask