# ElectronJS - Make bold text in Teaxtarea with local keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, electron, textarea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to make a text editor in ElectronJS as my first application in Electron.
I got the Textarea and the shortcut setup as it should be, but I cant get the selected text in the textarea to get bold, when pressing CTRL+B. I could use some help in the right direction on how this is done.

I have tried to use the execCommand so far to toggle the bold, but are getting the error:
*Document is not defined*

**Main.js**

```js
menu.append(new MenuItem({
    label: 'Shortcuts',
    submenu: [{
        role: 'Bold',
        accelerator: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Cmd+B' : 'Ctrl+B',
        click: () => { 
            document.execCommand('bold');
        }
    }]
}))
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

I have also tried this in `renderer.js`, but not working aswell.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually answered the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12831155/652535

**Content from link:**

If you need to customize your textarea, reproduce its behavior using another element (like a DIV) with the contenteditable attribute.

It's more customizable, and a more modern approach, textarea is just for plain text content, not for rich content.

```
<div id='fake_textarea' contenteditable></div>
```

The scrollbars can be reproduced with the CSS overflow property.

You can use this fake textarea in a form normally, i.e: if you have to submit its content through POST method, you could do something like(with jQuery):

```
<input type='hidden' id='fake_textarea_content' name='foobar' />
```

...

```
$('#your_form').submit(function()
{
  $('#fake_textarea_content').val($('#fake_textarea').html());
});
```