# Highlight things from the start of '<' till '>' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a text area, what I want to do is, where ever they type `<ANYTAG>` that tag should be highlighted. That means wherever they write tags, they should be highlighted with any colour, is it possible?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=highlight+html+tags+in+textarea

Comment: Check that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea

Comment: I don't find the answer.

Comment: textarea does *not* accept DOM elements in it, it's just text, hence the straight forward answer is: **no**, not with a textarea, unless you use complicated tricks via CSS, overlays, etc.