# Fill DIV child's content to overall grid layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to manage the grid with `css` on my site. Using `Bootstrap 4`.x I created both divs to have the same height using `display:grid`. My problem is I don't know how to manage the kids inside. I try to make the `contenteditable` div and [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea) `Javascript` show the user server-side information. I can't get the DIV height to work with parent content. I do not want to hard-code its height. I would like to define based on inheritance.

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12" style="display: grid;">
        <div class="card shadow mb-4">          
            <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h6 class="card-title m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
                    param
                </h6>
            </div>              
            <div class="card-body">             
                <div class="row mb-2">                  
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                        <textarea rows="13" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
                    </div>                      
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12" style="display: grid;">
        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h6 class="card-title m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
                    consol
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row mb-2">                  
                    <div id='console' class='mb-2'
                        style="min-height: 150px; border-radius: 5px; resize: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; background-color: #f8f8f8; padding: 2px 2px;"
                        name="console" contenteditable="false"></div>
                </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For better understanding and visualisation i made an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH85K.png).

Comment: Please add css. A minimal reproducible example would be best

Comment: A CSS of what exacly? You want me to provide all Bootstrap 4 backend? Iam not changing its original code, using style="" to overwrite.

Comment: Your html, when added into a bootstrap 4 playground, behaves differently from the picture. Answering your original question, try setting the height of child to 100%. I suggest using the browser inspector in situations like these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to setup second card-body row height:100% ; Bootstrap has class "h-100".

```
            <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row mb-2" style="height:100%">                  
                <div id='console' class='mb-2'
                    style="min-height: 150px; border-radius: 5px; resize: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; background-color: #f8f8f8; padding: 2px 2px;"
                    name="console" contenteditable="false"></div>
            </div>                  
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a BS-class to fill the div to the parent height. It's called `h-100`. Just check whether the row-div is also 100% at height.

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12" style="display: grid;">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h6 class="card-title m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
                        consol
                    </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row h-100 mb-2">                  
                        <div id='console' class='h-100 mb-2'
                            style="min-height: 150px; border-radius: 5px; resize: none; width: 100%; border: 0px; background-color: #f8f8f8; padding: 2px 2px;"
                            name="console" contenteditable="false"></div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried to implement this solution but it didnt change anything. Are you sure its the right place in this case for it?

Comment: I added h-100 to the div#console. Just add h-100 to div.row as well:  <div class="row h-100 mb-2">

Comment: Yep! this worked as well! pinned ED Wu solution becouse its more editable since u can adjust to simple % matter not just 25/50/75/100. But thanks a ton for your contibution!

Comment: You're welcome. You can find more about this in the [BS4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/).