# How to pass JSX to textarea component as children?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, textarea

I have the following react text area component:

```
<Textarea
  autoFocus
  placeholder={(formState.commentBody && formState.commentBody !== '') ? formState.commentBody : intl.get('issue_details_placeholder_add_a_comment')}
  value={formState.commentBody}
  onChange={handleChange('commentBody')}
  ref={$textareaRef}
/>
```

what gets displayed in the textarea is just `formState.commentBody` and `Textarea` is defined as:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import TextareaAutoSize from 'react-textarea-autosize';
import { StyledTextarea } from './Styles';

const Textarea = forwardRef(({ className, invalid, onChange, ...textareaProps }, ref) => (
  <StyledTextarea className={className} invalid={invalid}>
    <TextareaAutoSize
      {...textareaProps}
      onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value, event)}
      ref={ref || undefined}
    />
  </StyledTextarea>
));

export default Textarea;
```

Now, instead of passing a string (`formState.commentBody`) as value into `Textarea`, I want to pass some jsx code:

```
<blockquote>
    this is a customizable text and clickable within textarea 
</blockquote>
```

into `<textarea>` as its children, such that it would be equivalent to :

```
<textarea>
    <blockquote>
        this is a customizable text and clickable within textarea 
    </blockquote>
</textarea>
```

The final goal is to be able to display block code inside the `TextareaAutoSize`.

How can I achieve this?

I tried to code inside the `TextareaAutoSize` component directly like this:

```
const Textarea = forwardRef(({ className, invalid, onChange, ...textareaProps }, ref) => (
  <StyledTextarea className={className} invalid={invalid}>
    <TextareaAutoSize
      {...textareaProps}
      onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value, event)}
      ref={ref || undefined}
    >

      <blockquote>
        hahaha
      </blockquote>

    </TextareaAutoSize>
  </StyledTextarea>
));

export default Textarea;
```

However it is displaying:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: you mean something as - say `const someJSX = <div>hello</div>` and we can use as `<div>{someJSX}</div>`

Comment: the permitted content of a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#technical_summary) is text, it doesn't support child elements.

Comment: @KcH not sure why putting `<div>' around `someJSX` again when is has `<div>` already ?

Comment: see: [Format text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea)

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C just as an e.g., Thanks pilchard, that makes sense ... 

Answer (score 1):

> Now, instead of passing a string (formState.commentBody) as value into Textarea, I want to pass some jsx code.

The value of a text area is a *string* (text), not markup ([spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element)). Although you could use JSX to create content for it, you'd have to render those elements to a string in order to make them the value of a textarea (via [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) or similar), like this:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Textarea = ({children, value, updateValue}) => {
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        value = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(children);
    }
    return (
        <textarea value={value} onChange={() => {/*...*/}} />
    );
};

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <Textarea>
            <blockquote>
                this is a customizable text and clickable within textarea
            </blockquote>
        </Textarea>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js"></script>
```

But there's no point in doing that vs. just creating a string in the first place, and it's not updateable. (I couldn't tell from the question whether you wanted to be able to update it...but it's a `textarea`, so...) You'd have to pull apart the bits of it in order to then use those bits when recreating the element. A string would be updateable, so I'd suggest just using a string:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Textarea = ({value, updateValue}) => {
    const onChange = ({currentTarget: {value}}) => {
        updateValue(value);
    };
    return (
        <textarea value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    );
};

const initialCommentBody = `<blockquote>
    this is a customizable text and clickable within textarea
</blockquote>`;
const Example = () => {
    const [ commentBody, setCommentBody ] = useState(initialCommentBody);
    return (
        <Textarea value={commentBody} updateValue={setCommentBody} />
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: My goal is to be able to have 2 things in a comment text box: 1. block quote; 2. clickable link; The comment text box is currently implemented with `textarea`, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: I don't think `renderToString` has any effect here since any html placed in a text area will automatically be rendered as a string

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C - You can't have interactive content inside interactive content, and as I noted above, you can't have elements within a `textarea` at all. You could use a content-editable div as shown in [the question pilchard noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea), but then the link wouldn't be clickable while the div was editable.

Comment: @DannyMoshe - That's the point of it: To convert the React elements into a string to pass to the `textarea`. You can't have actual elements in a `textarea`, as I pointed out at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C - You could play games like detecting where the click was in the text, determining whether it was in the link, and then triggering the link, but that's surprising behavior (not usually good! :-) ) and probably not accessible (for screen readers and other assistive technology).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Thank you for the detailed answer. From the first paragraph and the code link, I see that the best we can achieve with `textarea` is to show the string `<blockquote>...` instead of `[object Object]`. That's enough reason to abandon using `textarea` ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  It seems that using a open source react Rich-text editor is the way to go then.

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed html content in a `textarea` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)). To do this, you could consider using a [content-editable div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable):

```
<div contenteditable="true">
 <blockquote>hahaha</blockquote>
</div>
```